# Logitech - LGHUB Lua - infinite Loop with break

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

***Hello ppl i work on lua script*** , all work perfect but ...

When "capslock" is ON and "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED"   >>>> MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)

All is ok about that , but i block during 2 month about how implant Infinite loop for MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)

***exemple :***
When "capslock" is ON and "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" **i want infinite loop MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)**

**and when "capslock" is OFF i want stop the infinite loop**

here my code :

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

        if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)  -- to prevent it from being stuck on
    end

    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        recoilx4 = not recoilx4
        spot = not spot
    end

   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoilx4 ) then  
if recoilx4 
then         
repeat
                                
Sleep(8)                               
MoveMouseRelative(0, 2.5)                               
Sleep(8                                
MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)                               
Sleep(8)
                                
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> When "capslock" is ON and "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" i want infinite loop MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)
> and when "capslock" is OFF i want stop the infinite loop

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
      repeat
         Sleep(8)
         MoveMouseRelative(0, 2.5)
         Sleep(8)
         MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)
         Sleep(8)
      until not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")
   end
end
```

Comment: Wow thank alot Egor,    faster answer and work Perfectly  ,   u amazing ,  10/10 !

Answer (score 0):

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        on = not on
    end
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and on then
      repeat
         Sleep(8)
         MoveMouseRelative(0, 2.5)
         Sleep(8)
         MoveMouseRelative(-52, 0)
         Sleep(8)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```